# Notification showing on admin panel using PHP, Codeigniter & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I working on an admin panel using PHP, Codeigniter & Mysql, I want to notify each user according to there userid on there dashboard. Could anyone help me to resolve this. I am unknown to this... Please help me! Thanks

Comment: And where is your trying code? What you want to notify user?

Comment: I new to this notification concept sir, I have created an admin panel where for travel agency where 3 types of user work on it 1.Account 2. tickeitng 3. Sales agent. Now each user do conversation on this panel when agent initiate booking of ticket through this panel the ticketing team will be notifying , after that ticketing team will book the ticket and initiate Quality check (QC Link) to the accounting team then accounting team check all the procedures and remarks the QC to Approved Status to the ticketing team after that ticketing team book the final ticket and reply to the agent. Plz help.

Comment: you are give the description that you want but what are you trying as code?

Comment: Sir, I've not coded yet... I want the idea about how to done it.

Comment: ok lets come in chat

Comment: Which Service u want to chat with me

Comment: I'm using whatsApp! and Skype both

Comment: You want notification in admin panel only?

Comment: Or you want mobile notification also?

Comment: I want the notification in admin panel only.

Answer (score 1):

To show notifications you need have the below structure.

1. Create a form where any user can submit message by selecting user.
2. Create a notifications table where you can store user messages. This table should keep information like who sent it, who will receive it, when to show, created and status (shown or not shown).
3. Next is to show the user his messages. This can be achieved by ajax. This is a costly affair as this needs regular hits to server to check / fetch the messages received by the user. 
   Or else you can show the notifications when user loads the page. This is not preferred as he needs to do some action on his browser.

Note: Using jquery for notifications is old fashioned. You can use nodejs for notifications purpose.

Comment: I new to this notification concept sir, I have created an admin panel where for travel agency where 3 types of user work on it 1.Account 2. tickeitng 3. Sales agent. Now each user do conversation on this panel when agent initiate booking of ticket through this panel the ticketing team will be notifying , after that ticketing team will book the ticket and initiate Quality check (QC Link) to the accounting team then accounting team check all the procedures and remarks the QC to Approved Status to the ticketing team after that ticketing team book the final ticket and reply to the agent. Plz help

Comment: First try to fulfill the 3 steps. Then you can trigger your messages in any step you want by inserting the messages at the right action on your website.

Comment: Okey, Thanks Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Afterall your description and which is i am understood you can do this:

1. Agent book the ticket for particular user (Set the status is 1 or anything you want in the DB. By default it is 0)
2. When click on the ticket show the list of users in sidebar which have the status is 1(with id) and give the count of users also
3. After that ticketing team will book the ticket and initiate Quality check (QC Link) to the accounting team (give the link and one another status
   which has option a)approve b)disappove---By default it is disapprove)
4. When QC open that link show the ticket form which is saved previously and give the 2 buttons in the end(Approve, Disaaprove)
5. If all the information is correct than approve otherwise disapprove.